# Sorting Android ListView based on checkbox selection

Tags: android, sorting, android-listview

I have ListView with custom adapter with checkBox based on list of installed apps with ViewHolder and the following checkBoxClickListener:

```
CheckBox.OnClickListener checkBoxClickListener = new CheckBox.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String packageName = (String) v.getTag();
            boolean isChecked = ((CheckBox) v).isChecked();
            if (isChecked) {
                Main.getStorage().write(packageName, "1");
            } else {
                Main.getStorage().write(packageName, "0");
            }
        }
    };
```

Dataset is based on on PackageInfo taken from PackageManager.getInstalledPackages().

What is the simplest and/or fastest way to sort my ListView to have all checked items on top of it?

Comment: For Custom Adapter if you are using Custom Object for Data adapter than use boolean field (of-course it is your checkbox value) in that object and just sort your list with this field (Custom Filter). (Also you can use Alphabatic of App name in extra filed).

Comment: There are few solutions for your case. You can use an Adapter and fill the List filled with all checked items on top, and then append with all unchecked items afterwards. Would you like sample code for that?

Comment: Another technique I think is to create a class where all checked items have priority over unchecked items. That means the checked item has an extra data member signifying priority. The class provides a comparison routine. This may be harder but follows good data encapsulation.

Comment: @TheOriginalAndroid, yes, the code sample for the first solution would be interesting. Additional question for me is how to do sorting as fast as possible, because the apps list loading itself is time consuming on some devices. And I guess that your first solution may be more optimal for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just Example:

```
class App {

    private String packageName;
    private boolean checked;
    // Other fields

    // +accessor methods ..
    public boolean isChecked()
    {
      return this.checked;
    }

    public void setChecked(boolean flag)
    {
      this.checked = flag;
    }
}
```

And use **Collection** sort for App list like,

```
Collections.sort(listApps, new Comparator<App>() {

        public int compare(App a1, App a2) {
            return (a1.isChecked() == a2.isChecked());
        }
    });
```

and than just call `notifyDatasetChanged()` on your List Adapter.

Comment: The answer is, just standard java practice code and assumption how it looks like.

Comment: is packageName relevant?

Comment: @LazyNinja - Means? In my answer, its just a example, how the custom data class looks like.

Comment: Thank you! I thought you have to define the package name for the example to work.

Comment: @user370305, your answer is useful but my dataset is based not on custom object, but on PackageInfo taken from PackageManager.getInstalledPackages(). Of course I could wrap it, but maybe there is also more simple and possibly optimized way to do that. Thank you!

Comment: public int compare(App a1, App a2) {
            return (a1.isChecked() == a2.isChecked());
        }

This Function's return value is int and its returning boolean? How it can be work?